# Complexification of the real lie algebra $\mathrm{sp}(m,n)$

Tags: lie-groups

I am unable to verify the fact that the complexification of the real lie algebra $\mathrm{sp}(m,n)$ is $\mathrm{sp}(2(m+n),\mathbf C)$, where $\mathrm{sp}(m,n)$ is the set of endomorphisms preserving the Hermitian bilinear form over the quaternions and $\mathrm{sp}(2n,\mathbf C)$ is the set of endomorphism preserving the skew symmetric bilinear form over complex numbers. It will be helpful to me if some one tell me some source.

I verified that
complexification  of $\mathrm{sp}(m,n)$ is isomorphic to a conjugate of  $\mathrm{sp}(2n,\mathbf C)$. I want to find  that matrix which conjugate          $\mathrm{sp}(2n,\mathbf C)$  and complexification  of $\mathrm{sp}(m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

A brief (but sufficient!) justification is given in William Fulton, Joe Harris, *Representation Theory: A First Course*. Springer-Verlag, $1991$.

---

**Edit.** It seems you also got an answer for this question over at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/129082/complexification-of-the-real-lie-algebra-spm-n)?